# How can I blur a photo and fade in text at the same time on hover (Jquery or Css)

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website I have some images that I want to blur on hover. A text should also fade in from the bottom at the same time. Here is an example of what I am talking about : [Freeletics.com](https://www.freeletics.com/en?gclid=CMrz_fPX2c4CFUNmGwodqygH5A)
.

I have tried this and I have both animations for bluring the photo and for fading in the text but I dont now how to position the text so that it doesn't disturb the :hover animation.

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: You can very well look into the source of the reference website and replicate it.

Comment: @Paulie_D I lost many nights searching for a good solution(also for my level of programming). Unfortunetly I deleted the code after I've seen that it hadn't worked. The solution of Herm Luna was perfect for my level of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.pokerconnection.net/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Liv-Boeree-poker-star-babe-girl-play.jpg">

  <div class="over">
    <p class="title">Ddey</p>
    <p class="rayal">text over here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.over {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.rayal {
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.over:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2et84zpo/

I created this fiddle for you. I think the effect is similar. Just style the text. Cheer. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.cover{
  background: url('https://cdn.freeletics.com/images/landing_page/boxes/box_1@2x.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}

.cover span{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}

.cover:hover{
  background-color: rbga(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.cover:after{
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
.cover:hover:after{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.cover:hover span{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <span>some random text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want **BLUR** effect.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  transition: .2s;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: .2s;
}
.wrapper:hover .image {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.wrapper:hover .text {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<figure class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="http://beerhold.it/300/200">
  <figcaption class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could Try CSS Filters:

```
.blur {
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

As well as Animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Read the Tutorials and maybe do something like this:

```
$("#img").hover(){
  $('#title').animateCss('bounce');
}
```

P.s Make sure you have learnt how to activate Animate.css through jQuery like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
animateCss: function (animationName) {
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
    });
 }
});
```

Hope this helped you!